# Sqlalchemy CLOB returns differing results on windows and Mac

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy

Given the following code
the output on windows has full 8bit bytes where as on the Mac the string has been encoded as a 7bit ASCII with what looks like 'replace' on the encoding.

**MAC**
25 50 44 46 2d 31 2e 33 0a 25 **43 69 3f 3f** 0a 35 20 30 20 6f 62 6a 0a 3c 3c 2f

**WINDOWS**
25 50 44 46 2d 31 2e 33 0a 25 **c7 ec 8f a2** 0a 35 20 30 20 6f 62 6a 0a 3c 3c 2f

I have the same version of sqlalchemy, python, cx-oracle and instant client installed

I have tried different convert_unicode/coerse_unicode type flags to no avail

Any help would be appreciated

```
from sqlalchemy import Table, MetaData
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.sql import select


if __name__ == '__main__':

  connection_string = 'oracle+cx_oracle://user:pw@db:1521/orcl'
  engine_args = {
    'echo': False,
    'convert_unicode': True,
    'coerce_to_unicode': True
  }
  src_engine = create_engine(connection_string, **engine_args)
  metadata = MetaData()

  table = Table('POLICY_CONTRACT', metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=src_engine, schema='TROPICS_POLICY')
  s = select(table.columns)
  q = src_engine.execute(s)
  r = q.fetchone()

  for k in r.keys():
    v = r[k]
    if k == 'contract_content':
      v1 = " ".join(["{0:02x}".format(ord(x)) for x in v])
      print("{0} : {1} : {2}\n".format(k, type(v), v[:100]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a guess, but your Oracle *client* character set may be different between your Windows setup and the Mac setup.  When the client character set is different than the data requires, there may be some conversion that takes place.  From the [Globalization Support Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch2charset.htm#NLSPG164):

> Setting NLS_LANG correctly enables proper conversion from the client
>   operating system character encoding to the database character set.
>   When these settings are the same, Oracle Database assumes that the
>   data being sent or received is encoded in the same character set as
>   the database character set, so character set validation or conversion
>   may not be performed. This can lead to corrupt data if conversions are
>   necessary.
>
> During conversion from one character set to another, Oracle Database
>   expects client-side data to be encoded in the character set specified
>   by the NLS_LANG parameter. If you put other values into the string
>   (for example, by using the CHR or CONVERT SQL functions), then the
>   values may be corrupted when they are sent to the database because
>   they are not converted properly. If you have configured the
>   environment correctly and if the database character set supports the
>   entire repertoire of character data that may be input into the
>   database, then you do not need to change the current database
>   character set. However, if your enterprise becomes more globalized and
>   you have additional characters or new languages to support, then you
>   may need to choose a character set with a greater character repertoire

You can check the *server* setup by checking:

```
select * from v$nls_parameters;
```

Check for NLS_CHARACTERSET

On the Windows client, check the registry for NLS_LANG entry (or echo %NLS_LANG% if the env variable is set).  On Unix/Linux, try echo $NLS_LANG.  Not sure about Mac, but perhaps the Unix approach would work too. (if its not set, I believe it defaults to US7ASCII)

If the Mac is different than your db server (I'm guessing Mac is US7ASCII), then try exporting a different NLS_LANG first, then running your queries.  For example

```
export NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8ISO8859P1
```

More detail [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch3globenv.htm#NLSPG189)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction
I sorted the issue by adding the following line to my python script
  os.putenv('NLS_LANG', 'AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8MSWIN1252')

Comment: The above setting didn't work for me with python 3 so I ended up using   os.putenv('NLS_LANG', '_.WE8ISO8859P1')
which is LATIN1

Comment: great to hear it helped, if this solved your issue feel free to accept the answer, thanks